# count how many time a certain string appears in a given string

Tags: for-loop, count

Write a program to find how many times substring “Emma” appears in the given string.

I found the first solution and it's easy but the second solution i don't understand the part in the middle
can someone help me please?

````
python

#1 solution

```python

str = "Emma is good develober. Emma is a writer "
print("Emma appeared", str.count("Emma"), "time")
````

#2 solution

```py
def count_emma(statement):
    print("Given String: ", statement)
    count = 0

    for i in range(len(statement) - 1):
        count += statement[i: i + 4] == 'Emma'
    return count


count = count_emma("Emma is good developer. Emma is a writer")
print("Emma appeared ", count, "times")
```

Comment: If you write `print(statement[i : i + 4])` above the `count += ... ` line, this should help you understand what is happening

Comment: what do mean by that?  where should write it